# Kernel modules __init macro in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros

I want to create a loadable kernel module for Linux.
This is the code

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init mymodule_init(void)
{
 printk ("My module worked!\n");
        return 0;
}

static void __exit mymodule_exit(void)
{
 printk ("Unloading my module.\n");
        return;
}

module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Pay now attention to the `__init` macro. As the doc says:

> The __init macro indicates to compiler that that associated function
>   is only used during initialization. Compiler places all code marked
>   with __init into  a special memory section that is freed after
>   initialization

I'm trying to understand why the initialization method can end up leaking memory. Is it due to the FIFO disposition of function calls in the stack ?

Comment: What in the above quote indicates leaking memory?

Comment: The need of putting the __init method in a special memory section

Comment: "...that is freed after initilaization"? Doesn't seem like a leak to me.

Comment: *Is it due to the FIFO disposition of function calls in the stack* -- what? A stack is not even a FIFO structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very broad strokes:

Executable code (what source code is compiled into) takes up memory. A modern CPU would read the section of memory where the instructions reside, and execute them. For most user space applications, the code segment of a processes memory is loaded once, and is never changed during program execution. The code is always there, unless programmers play around with it.

This isn't a problem, since the OS will manage the processes virtual memory and cold code segments will eventually be unloaded into a swap file. Physical memory is never "wasted" like that in user space.

For the kernel, where code runs in privileged mode, nothing will "unload" unused pages as happens in user mode. If a function is placed into the kernels regular code segment, it will take up physical memory for as long as the kernel runs, which can be quite a long time. If a function is only called once, that's quite a waste of space.

Now while loadable kernel modules can be loaded and unloaded in general, so their code may not take up space indefinitely, it's still somewhat wasteful to take up space for a function that is only going to be called once.

Since moderns CPU's treat code as a form of executable data, it's possible to place that data into a memory segment that is not retained indefinitely. The function is loaded, then called, and then the segment can be used for something else. This is what the `__init` macro instructs the compiler to do. To emit code which can be easily unloaded after being called.

Comment: You are fantastic thanks. For which reasons kernel memory is not swappable ?
ps: in user process is the code that take up memory or are the function calls in the stack ?

Comment: @Tantaros - The call stack doesn't contain code, it contains the variables of a call and an instruction pointer for the return (among other things). That pointer is a place in the executable code. The code is separate from the stack itself, in another segment altogether. As for the kernel not being subject to swapping, that's a big can of complications that best avoided.